# Call multiple functions at same time

Tags: c#, asynchronous, parallel-processing

I have function call as below:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            StreamLoader loader = new StreamLoader();
            StreamConsumer consumer = new StreamConsumer();

            try
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Loader feeds to respective queues.....");
                loader.DonwloadFeeds();

                Console.WriteLine("Processing queued feeds.....");
                consumer.ProcessQueuedFeeds();

            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                logger.append(ex.Message, Logger.LogLevel.ERROR);
            }
        }
```

How do I start both downloading messages and processing them at same time. I want to call/invoke both functions at same time.
I am using C#.

Comment: Were your two methods written to be concurrent?

Answer (score 6):

```
Parallel.Invoke(() => loader.DonwloadFeeds(), () => consumer.ProcessQueuedFeeds());
```

See:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd537609(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: FYI, your try-catch should be placed outside Parallel.Invoke. All of the errors will be wrapped in an AggregateException :D http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd992634(v=vs.110).aspx